# How to watch a collection change in Angular 5 within a Service

Tags: angular, observable, aurelia, observablecollection

I'm trying to watch for an array collection change inside an Angular Service and I can't seem to figure out on how to do that in Angular 5. Basically, I am looking for the same thing as `$watchCollection` that we used to have in AngularJS, which is dirty checking and I'm aware of that.

I want to detect changes from within a Service, so I don't think I can or should use `@Input`. Also the array that I want to watch for changes, is a property inside an object. The reference that I have inside the Service is `this.columnDefinition.collection` (which the `collection` is an array of objects). Basically if I push a new object to the `collection` array, I want to detect it and do another action.

I tried to use `IterableDiffers` and `DoCheck` but that doesn't seem to detect or trigger when the `collection` array changes.

I also tried using `Observable.of` on the array (with `RxJS 5`), but this gets executed only on the first time

```
const observer = Observable.of(this.columnDefinition.collection);
observer.subscribe((col) => console.log(col))
```

I thought I could use `ofArrayChanges` but that got removed from ES6 consideration, and so it also got removed from `RxJS 5` and up

I'm also trying to do this without using `Subject` since I want the user to only manipulate the array. They shouldn't know there's an observer attach to it

If I compare to the Aurelia framework, I can do exactly that with the following

```
this.bindingEngine
      .collectionObserver(this.columnDefinition.collection)
      .subscribe((changes: { index: number, addedCount: number, removed: any[] }[]) => {
         console.log('changes ', changes);
         console.log('updated collection', this.columnDefinition.collection);
      });
```

and it works, there's nothing fancy here.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, the question is more about, can this be done **without** any special functions or any changes to the array? I know that I can do it with a `Subject` and an `next` but I'm trying to avoid that (if possible). I want the user to still use regular array `push`, `pop`, `slice`, ... If Aurelia can do it, is that also doable in Angular? ...it used to with `$watchCollection` in AngularJS so is there an equivalent in Angular 5?

Answer (score 1):

Because Array is using reference

```
this.columnDefinition.collection.push(// something);
```

This will affect the data inside array of course, but the `reference` to that array in this case `collection` is not changed.
Therefor if you want others component that subscribe to your observable to notify the change, you should also change the `reference` itself.

For example:
Service:

```
private collections: Collection[];//the data that will be emit
private collectionsSubject: BehaviorSubject<Collection[]>;//The subject to emit data
collections$: Observable<Collection[]>;//The public observable that other components will subscribe to
constructor() {
  this.collections = [];
  this.collectionsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Collection[]>(this.collections);

  this.collections$ = this.collectionsSubject.asObservable();
}


//When ever other place all to this service to add new collection emit new data with new reference

addCollection(collection: Collection) {
  this.collections.push(collection);
  //Here we will renew the reference and passing it to others component using spread operator
  this.fetchOptionsSubject.next([...this.collections]);
}
```

Component:

```
this.collectionService.collections$.subscribe((collections: Collection[]) => {
  this.collections = collections;
});
```

You could learn more about [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thanks but if I understand your answer correctly, you are requiring me to use `addCollection` instead of a simple array push. My question is more about, is this achievable **without** any special function call. Oh and yes I know about the spread operator, thanks

Comment: So `this.collections = [...this.collections, collection]`, so instead pushing collection directly to your collections, you could clone a new `reference` to `this.collections` with a new `collection` being push like this

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, are you saying it would work just by using the spread operator? But even if it works, that still mean that it won't work with a regular `push`, `pop` or `slice`, right?